# Under windows, how to allocate a "write combining" memory block?

Tags: memory-management

The main motivation: to use the movntdqa assembler command to avoid stack pollution. This command only works with write combining memory (also called WS and USWC)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass PAGE_WRITECOMBINE  to VirtualAllocEx(). Sequential writes to that page will be write-combined by the MMU. Reads or nonsequential writes will induce a severe performance penalty.

Comment: i tried it:

char *ans=(char * ) VirtualAllocEx (hProcess, 0,1024*1024*64, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE| PAGE_WRITECOMBINE); it always returns 0 with GetLastError=87
when replaceing PAGE_WRITECOMBINE with PAGE_NOCACHE, it does work and indeed memory access is very slow. but i need write combining so that movntdqa  works as advertised.

Comment: Hmm. Try creating the page and then changing its permissions after the fact with VirtualProtectEx() ?

Comment: does not work either, the code below still returns 87
unsigned long old;
err=VirtualProtectEx(hProcess,ans,size,PAGE_READWRITE|PAGE_WRITECOMBINE,&old);

Comment: Gosh, I'm stumped. It seems like your version of the Windows kernel isn't aware of write combined memory and rejects the parameter (that error code is "invalid parameter").

Comment: i tested using XP Professional with SP3, and vista home edition.